# JS Regexp - how to find text in a string

Tags: javascript, regex

There is some text, exp: "The string class is an instantiation of the basic_string class template that uses char".

I need to find the text - "basic_string", but if there is no word "the" in front of him.

If use negative lookbehind, it was be:

```
(?<!\sthe)\s+basic_string
```

But javascript not understand negative lookbehind, what to do?

Comment: Also, here are links to a couple videos I found on the subject. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pwX8HmJKfLo and https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S8pyWg_p3CQ

Answer (score 3):

If the only allowed character between "the" and "basic_string" is the white-space:

```
([^e\s]|[^h]e|[^t]he)\s+basic_string
```

Comment: I saw this question, and thought it a particularly good one. Not sure exactly what's going on here, but this solution works. It can be tested here: https://regex101.com/r/vX5rJ5/1

Comment: This [does not always work](https://regex101.com/r/vX5rJ5/2) (also, [here](https://regex101.com/r/vX5rJ5/3)).

Comment: `(^|[^e\s]|(^|[^h])e|(^|[^t])he|\wthe)\s+basic_string` covers even those particular cases.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [xregexp library](http://xregexp.com/) to get advanced regex features like lookbehind in Javascript.

**Alternatively** you can use alternation and capture group as a *workaround*:

```
var s = 'The string class is an instantiation of the basic_string class template that uses char';

var kw = s.match(/\bthe basic_string\b|(\bbasic_string\b)/)[1];
// undefined

s = 'instantiation of basic_string class template'
kw = s.match(/\bthe basic_string\b|(\bbasic_string\b)/)[1]
//=> "basic_string"
```

In this regex, captured group #1 will only be **populated** if `bbasic_string` isn't preceded by word `the`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `RegExp` `/(the)(?\sbasic_string)/` or `new RegExp("(" + before + ")(?=" + match + ")")`  to match `"the"` if followed by `" basic_string"`, `.match()` to retrieve `.index` of matched string, `.slice()` to get `"basic_string"`

```js
var str = "The string class is an instantiation of the basic_string class template that uses char";
var before = "the";
var match = " basic_string";
var index = str.match(new RegExp("(" + before + ")(?=" + match + ")")).index 
            + before.length + 1;
console.log(str.slice(index, index + match.length));
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to emulate the negative lookbehind is via an optional capturing group, and check if the group participated in the match:

```
/(\bthe)?\s+basic_string/g
 ^^^^^^^^
```

See this JS demo:

```js
var s = 'The string class is an instantiation of the basic_string class template that uses char, not basic_string.';
var re = /(\bthe)?(\s+basic_string)/gi;
var res = s.replace(re, function(match, group1, group2) {
   return group1 ? match : "<b>" + group2 + "</b>";
});
document.body.innerHTML = res;
```